# Run Jenkins job all the time

Tags: jenkins, job-scheduling

I've a Jenkins job I want to keep running all the time. When a build is ending, I want to immediately trigger another build. How can I do that?

Thanks, Omer

Comment: What are you really trying to achive? What is this job supposed to do? Maybe there's some additional answer if you add the details to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different job configurations for that:

1. **Build Triggers** -> **Build after other projects are built**
2. Add a post-build action **Build other projects**

In both cases, you can enter your own Project, so it'll be triggered again every time a build is completed. You can also specify if this should be done only while the project is stable.

There is however one (probably more) drawback in this approach, which is that it'll create enormous overview pages, where all build triggers are listed:

[image: trigger history]

So i'd recommend to do something else and for example use the Jenkins API to trigger a new build. There are many ways to do that, one simple example is adding a build step **Execute shell** and do something like:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/$JOB_NAME/build
```

If you have configured the Jenkins URL, you could also use `$JOB_URL`. You can also add post parameters to trigger a parameterized build.

Comment: So what you are saying is that job will call itself right before it ends?

Comment: If you're using the shell approach, yes. When using the upstream/downstream approach, the new build will be triggered when the previous build is finished. Regardless of the actual solution, jenkins will not build a project concurrently by default but queue the follow up build until the "triggering" build is actually finished.